# Using QtCreator with konsole instead of xterm

Tags: terminal, console, terminal-emulator, konsole, qtcreator

I tried to use KDE's Konsole to start console applications from QtCreator.
The application works as intended, but any new instance of Konsole started during or after the execution just shows this:

```
Cannot read creator env file /tmp/QtCreator.UiK966: No such file or directory
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

or a similar error

```
Cannot connect creator comm socket Qt Creator console
```

The second one is not complete because it didn't occur anymore and I can't find the text anymore.
Closing ALL instances of Konsole fixes the problem until I start any console project from QtCreator again.

QtCreator Tools/Options/Environment/System/Terminal is set to /usr/bin/konsole -e

QtCreator appends the following to the command set in Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/../libexec/qtcreator/qtcreator_process_stub run /tmp/QtCreator.GJt966/stub-socket "Press <RETURN> to close this window..." /home/zzt/.build/untitled-Desktop-Debug /tmp/QtCreator.UiK966 966 /home/zzt/.build/untitled-Desktop-Debug/untitled
```

There was a known bug in QtCreator that resulted in the described behaviour, but only in the Konsole instance that was started by QtCreator and that is supposedly fixed.

The problem occurs on a Oracle VirtualBox VM running Arch, but does not occur on my laptop running the same OS and the same Konsole&QtCreator versions. Configuration is similar on both systems but can definitely differ.

```
$ konsole --version
konsole 16.08.3
$ qtcreator -version
Qt Creator 4.1.0 based on Qt 5.7.0
...
$ uname -a
Linux archvm 4.8.8-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 17 14:51:03 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You provided the answer: konsole establishes one process to run all of the windows, and that gets confused by applications which assume otherwise.

Comment: So you suggest there is no possible fix for this even though the error does not occur on my laptop with more or less the same setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
konsole --nofork
```

This option disables the forking behavior and runs the new window in separate process.

Comment: For what it's worth, that option was added to konsole about a month later in c6ffcaff557760f46ba5813823868e656b45da0f